# Java Build tool flexible enough to do conditional checks

Tags: java, ant, build

I currently use Ant to build Java software.

However, all development that I have done so far was not very complex. So, ant was sufficient for me.

Recently, I have started working on a bit complex project that requires some conditional checks while building. I find doing that a little complex with ant.

Is there any better way to do conditional checks in Ant. Or please suggest me a better tool, if any.

PS: I am not a Ant Pro. So, I might be missing something. So, please let methose condition know if I am missing some feature of Ant.

Comment: You can also use [Gradle](http://gradle.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching build technology to [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) are the best choices if you're ready to embrace a more modern build technology.

On the other hand if you only need to occasionally extend your build logic I'd suggest an intermediate approach of embedding a scripting language within your build (Better in my opinion that using the ant-contrib tasks).

A good candiate is [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task), which has excellent integration with the parent ANT build settings. (Groovy is also the technology behind Gradle)

## Example

You did not indicate what kind of conditional checks you wanted to perform.

The following example parses all Java source files checking for the presence of the "hello world" string.
When found it sets the ANT property **somethingwrong** which prevents the build from executing.,

```
<target name="build-checks" depends="init">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <fileset id="srcFiles"  dir="src/main/java" includes="**/*.java"/>

    <groovy>
    project.references.srcFiles.each { fileresource ->
        fileresource.file.eachLine { line ->
            if (line =~ /hello world/) {
                properties["somethingwrong"] = 1 // Signal build to do nothing

                println "Found \"hello world\" in the source code"
            }
        }
    }
    </groovy>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="build-checks" unless="somethingwrong">
    <echo message="everything ok"/>
</target>
```

Note how groovy can iterate thru an ANT fileset and set ANT properties.

Comment: +1 for the specific example but as noted in my answer if you use Java 6 then javascript is a tad simpler since you don't need to mess around with an external dependency on an interpreter.

Comment: Point taken. However, I use ivy to download all my build dependencies, making it very painless to include the groovy ANT task. I'm also a bit of a Javascript novice :-(

Answer (score 3):

Use ant-contrib.

It has if/then/else, foreach, variables (ie, properties which *can* be overriden), real regex matching etc.

It hasn't been updated for quite a while, but it still works. Why ant doesn't have such capabilities builtin is beyond me... I have asked several times on ant-users and never had a satisfactory answer.

Comment: +1 because ant-contrib will be the fastest and easiest way for the poster to introduce conditionals into his build script.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of this turning into a "what's your favourite build tool" question, your requirements to do conditional logic suggests that you need a proper programming language to coordinate your build. For this reason, I recommend [Gradle](http://gradle.org/), which uses the Groovy language to orchestrate various Ant and Maven-style subtasks.

While Ant-Contrib and Maven *can* do conditional logic, they're clumsy and difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) for basic conditional logic in ant.  Most of the time features of the tools and ability to add new features by plugin is more important. Ant comes with a collection of ready to use task, relatively easy to add new tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into creating custom tasks that encapsulate the conditional logic.  This is pretty easy using `<scriptdef>` (and even easier with Java 6 and its built-in Javascript interpreter) as you don't need to compile a separate artifact and deal with the resulting classpath mess.

You said you're not a pro, however.  Though creating custom tasks isn't hard it does require some experience.

Others have suggested gradle. I'm interested in gradle too, but the industry does still favor Ant and Maven.  Depending on the constraints of your project (or company), sometimes you do have to go with the flow.

While ant-contrib is a possible solution, as far as I can tell it's a dead project--it hasn't been updated in years.  Some of the tools it adds are simply obsolete, even dangerous, with more recent versions of Ant.  And I find conditional code in XML disgusting to read.

Instead, take a look at [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/), which provides an expression language add-on to Ant that, in addition to many other things, Flaka allows you to do conditional logic far beyond what you can do in pure Ant.

Comment: "Java 6 and its built-in Javascript interpreter" <-- Eh? I'm interested. Link?

Comment: Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html.  Note that <scriptdef> has worked in Ant for a while, but when Sun added javascript support to Java 6 it made things much, much simpler.

Comment: Whoops, that link is about the javax.scripting package.  Here's another about the built-in Rhino interpreter: http://onjava.com/onjava/2006/04/26/mustang-meets-rhino-java-se-6-scripting.html.

Answer (score 0):

you should investigate on Maven ( http://maven.apache.org/ ) to build complex projects.

Comment: maven has exactly the same problem as (base) ant with conditionals: it just can't do it easily.